# CSS !important doesn't work with mpdf

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I use mPDF to convert html file to pdf file, almost fine but `!important` property does not work. The code is below:

**CSS**:

```
td .style1 {border-left:2px #000000 solid !important;}
td .style2 {border-left:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1 style2">Something here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The result is border-left of `td` tag disappear. I think the reason is `style2` bellow `style1` and mPDF not know `!important` property. How can I fix this problem?

**Note**: html and css code is automatically generated, so I cannot delete `style2` because css class name can be changed every time it is generated.

**Note 2**: The border disappear in pdf file, which generated by mPDF. The border is fine with html in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two rules of the same type requesting two different things. Therefore the only logical thing to do next if you cannot remove style 2 is to create an inline style like this when it is generated:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td class="style1 style2" style="border-left:2px #00000 solid !important;">Something here</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This will effectively override the style-sheet entirely and use what you told it to use here.

Comment: Thank you @revofire, but my problem is html code is automatically generated too. So I don't know how many **td** tag have this problem and where they are.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your code only, Color code missing one ZERO (0) in style1, Rest is fine, so than style1 will get into act.

Change

```
td .style1 {border-left:2px #00000 solid !important;}
```

to

```
td .style1 {border-left:2px #000000 solid !important;}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you @JJRS. I mistyped. Edited. The css code is automatically generated, so it will always correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your css would be like this

```
td .style1 {border-left:2px #000000 solid !important;}
td .style2 {border-left:none;}
```

or

```
 td .style1 {border-left:2px #000 solid !important;}
    td .style2 {border-left:none;}
```

Color code should of six digit or 3 digit.. Please read some article about  color code

Comment: Thank you Adarsh Gowda K R. It is my mistyping only. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a more specific style for this combination:

```
td.style1, td.style1.style2  {border-left:2px #000000 solid;}
```

Answer (score 0):

mPDF have some Problems with multiple class usage, like class="style1 style2".
If possible reduce it to one.
For my projects I often use an inline css to fix this:

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

Inject it with your fixes in the html header before you generate the pdf.
The scond problem is that mPDF have problems with a list of tag/style definitions:

```
td.style1, td.style1.style2 ...
```

don't us this.

The other way is to replace multiple classes. If you can't change your html code.

```
$html = str_replace('class="style1 style2"', 'class="style1"', $html);
```

or to a different:

```
$html = str_replace('class="style1 style2"', 'class="style3"', $html);
```